# enum as class member function with return value

Tags: c++, enums, return

i am having trouble with the following:
i need to use enum to enumerate 4 inherited classes (at this point they have no difference between them other the the enum) and then return the type via a virtual function called "whoAmI", i don't understand the syntax as to how i would do the return part 
the following is the relevant code;

in class.h

```
virtual void whoAmI();
 enum gettype { easyTile, cropTile, waterTile, mediumTile};

in class.cpp

void tile::whoAmI()
{


}
```

Comment: change `void` to `gettype`?

Comment: This is basic C++ - `gettype whoAmI()`. I suggest you pick up a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and _read_ it.

Comment: BTW: "gettype" is a very strange noun (even in English). One would expect something like "TileType".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it like that:

```
class TileBase
{
public:
    enum Type { easyTile, cropTile, waterTile, mediumTile };

    virtual Type whoAmI() const = 0;
    virtual ~TileBase() = default;
};

class EasyTile : public TileBase
{
    Type whoAmI() const override { return easyTile; }    
};
```

You see, you need to specify the `enum Type` as return type instead of `void`.

Comment: thank you very much for the great and to-the-point answer

Answer (score 2):

You can change the return type of your function to the name of your `enum`, then use `= 0` to declare the base class is pure virtual.

```
class ITile
{
public:
    enum class EType { easy, crop, water, medium };
    virtual EType whoAmI() const = 0;
};
```

Then the derived classes can `override` this method to return the correct `enum` type, for example

```
class EasyTile : public ITile
{
public:
    EasyTile() = default;
    EType whoAmI() const override { return EType::easy; }
};

class CropTile : public ITile
{
public:
    CropTile() = default;
    EType whoAmI() const override { return EType::crop; }
};
```

So as an example ([live demo](http://cpp.sh/477y))

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ITile>> tiles;
    tiles.emplace_back(new EasyTile);
    tiles.emplace_back(new CropTile);
    for (auto const& tile : tiles)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(tile->whoAmI()) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Will output

```
0
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Tile{
public:
    enum getType { easyTile, cropTile, waterTile, mediumTile};
    virtual getType whoAmI(){}
};
class easyTile:public Tile{
public:
    getType whoAmI(){return getType::easyTile;}
};
class cropTile: public Tile{
public:
    virtual getType whoAmI(){return getType::cropTile;}
};
class waterTile: public Tile{
public:
    virtual getType whoAmI(){return getType::waterTile;}
};
class mediumTile: public Tile{
public:
    virtual getType whoAmI(){ return getType::mediumTile;}
};

int main() {
    Tile *T = new cropTile;
    cout << T->whoAmI() << endl;
    delete T;

    return 0;
}
```

Output : 1